# Does Homebrew-cask Support Architecture Based Distribution for Apple Silicon and Intel Processors?

Tags: macos, universal-binary

I am trying to distribute my app through homebrew-cask, but I have encountered an issue. The problem is that homebrew-cask doesn't support separate builds for Apple silicon and Intel processor macOS. Instead, we need a universal binary. My question is, does homebrew-cask provide architecture-based distribution support for the same app?

A solution except for universal binary and asking for help in creating the cask file.

Answer (score 0):

I read at "[Cask Cookbook / Conditional statements](https://docs.brew.sh/Cask-Cookbook#conditional-statements)":

> ### Handling different system configurations
>
> Casks can deliver specific versions of artifacts depending on the current macOS release or CPU architecture by either tailoring the URL / SHA-256 hash / version, using the [`on_<system>` syntax](https://docs.brew.sh/Formula-Cookbook#handling-different-system-configurations) (which replaces conditional statements using `MacOS.version` or `Hardware::CPU`), or both.
>
> If your cask's artifact is offered as separate downloads for Intel and Apple Silicon architectures, they will presumably be downloadable at distinct URLs that differ only slightly. To adjust the URL depending on the current CPU architecture, supply a hash for each to the `arm:` and `intel:` parameters of sha256, and use the special `arch` stanza to define the unique components of the respective URLs for substitution in the `url`. Additional substitutions can be defined by calling `on_arch_conditional` directly.

So try and create a Cask file with architecture conditional: you can specify different URLs and SHA-256 hashes for ARM (Apple Silicon) and Intel architectures.

```rb
cask "your-app" do
    arch arm: "arm64", intel: "x86_64"
    version "1.0.0"

    sha256 arm:   "sha256_arm64_version",
        intel: "sha256_x86_64_version"

    url "https://yourappdomain.com/downloads/YourApp_#{version}_#{arch}.dmg"
    name "YourApp"
    homepage "https://yourappdomain.com/"

    app 'YourApp.app'
end
```

Replace `sha256_arm64_version` and `sha256_x86_64_version` with the actual SHA-256 hashes of your ARM and Intel builds.
Adjust the `url` to point to where your different architecture builds are hosted.
Test the cask locally to make sure it works correctly on both architectures. Once tested, you can submit your cask to the Homebrew-Cask repository for inclusion.

---

An alternative approach would be to use the [`lipo` tool](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/building-a-universal-macos-binary#Update-the-Architecture-List-of-Custom-Makefiles) to combine your separate Apple Silicon and Intel builds into a single universal binary.

```bash
lipo -create -output YourAppUniversal YourAppIntel YourAppAppleSilicon
lipo -info YourAppUniversal
```

Then fork the [homebrew-cask repository](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask) on GitHub, and create a new cask file in the `Casks` directory.

```rb
cask 'your-app' do
    version '1.0.0'
    sha256 'your_app_sha256_hash'

    url 'https://yourappdomain.com/YourAppUniversal.dmg'
    name 'YourApp'
    homepage 'https://yourappdomain.com/'

    app 'YourApp.app'
end
```